# Derived class variable scope c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

Let's say we have two classes, `Base` and `Derived`. There are two methods, `getX` and `setX`, which are public and use a protected int `x` to interface with the user. `Base` construction sets `x` to 1, and `Derived` construction sets x to 3.

```
class Base {
public:
    Base();
    int getX();
    void setX(int n);
protected:
    int x;
}

int Base::getX() {
    return x;
}

void Base::setX(int n) {
    x = n;
}

Base::Base() : x(1) {
}

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived();
}

Derived::Derived() : x(3) {
}
```

The `Derived` class has full access to the methods from Base. Great.

Let's say that for some reason I don't want `setX` to be available to users of the `Derived` class. There are a couple ways I thought of doing it.

1) Redeclare `setX` as private in `Derived`, so shadowing prevents the user from accessing that method entirely.

2) Redeclare `x` as a private const int in `Derived`. However, this results in setX and getX working with Base::x.

3) Make Base::setX a virtual function, make a Derived::setX function that does nothing.

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: you should create a `Base(int n)` constructor, then you could do `Derived::Derived() : Base(3) {}` as it is now your code doesn't compile.

Comment: If you use method 1, it's possible to access the hidden function in a verbose way: `Derived d; d.Base::SetX(9);` - is this possibility desirable for your design, or do you want to prevent it too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `Derived` publicly derived from `Base`, what you are trying to do does not make much sense. You should instead use `private` or `protected` inheritance and then provide access in `Derived` only to methods from `Base` that you need, not the way around.

Comment: I would derive privately only if some virtual functions needed overriding. Otherwise I'd compose.

Answer (score 2):

First, as observed by anatolyg, shadowing `setX` method in 1) by making it private in `Derived` class does not prevent someone to call it on the `Base` class directly by casting.

So 1) is only ok if you accept this.

Otherwise, if you only want to provide an implementation of `setX` in `Base` class to many derived class, but without making it public either to `Base` or derived class user. just make `setX` method protected in `Base` class. In this case you could probably also make x private, and call `setX` method from `Derived` constructor.

If you only want to forbid user of any instance of `Derived` class to call the `setX` method on that object... but still have it in the interface, well obviously you could as you proposed in 3) make it a virtual function in Base and implement it empty in `Derived`.

But in this case you are going against the inheritance motto of "is a" (obviously your derived class doesn't behave like the Base class).

If what you are looking is a compilation error to forbid this call,
may be you could rethink your hierarchy:

- `class real_Base;` which does not implements `setX` method
- `class Base : public real_Base;` which implements `setX` method
- `class Derived : public real_Base;` which does not implement `setX` method

In this case then:

- you would use `real_Base` as interface when your client code does not need to call `setX`.
- use `Base` when call to `setX` is allowed
- use `Derived` when call to `setX` is forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't overriding any virtual functions so inheritance is dubious.

Do you want users to use the `Base` interface or the `Derived` interface? If you say `Derived`, again that's dubious.

Compose `Derived` from `Base` and give it a better name:

```
class Composite {
private:
    Base base;
public:
    Composite() : base(3) {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialize member `x` in the initializer list of `Derived`, since `x` is not a member of `Derived`.  Your compiler should issue an error.